# any does not work properly with 1D array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, any

I have a simple numpy 2D Array. E.g. :

```
M=np.array([[15,1,0],
            [19,5,2]])
```

which I loop over to check if in each line (axis 1)
a value exist greater than e.g. 2.
As the first value is always greater than 2, I slice the array to only check which of the other n values in that line is greater than 2.

```
#A    
for i in range(len(M)):
          if any(M[i,1:])>=2:
              disp('Super')
```

Or, as I am not so familiar with python yet, I also used this code, which should function the same, right?

```
#B    
for i in range(len(M)):
          if any(x>=2 in x in M[i,1:]):
              disp('Great')
```

**The Problem** I have now is that the any does not care about my slicing (M[i,1:]). It checks always the total array and of course finding a value greater than 2. 
I expected in the first itteration a FALSE and in the second a TRUE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

any(l) takes a list (or iterable) of values and returns True if any of the values it iterated over are truthy i.e. bool(value) == True. Therefore, it doesn't make sense to compare the output of any(...) with a number so I wouldn't do `any(M[i,1:])>=2`.

However, you can do `any(M[i, 1:] > 2)` where `M[i, 1:] > 2` broadcasts the greater than operator to each value of the given row and returns you a boolean array that `any` can operate over.